# What is the empirically found best value for n in n-gram model?

Tags: n-gram

I am implementing a variation of spell checker. After taking various routes (for improving the time efficiency)  I am planning to try out a component which would involve use of n-gram model. So essentially I want to prune the list of likely candidates for further processing. Would you guys happen to know if using one value of n (say 2) will be better over other (say 3)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://blogamundo.net/lab/wordlengths/), the average word length in English is 5.10 letters.  I would assume that people are more likely to misspell longer words than shorter words, so I'd lean towards going around maybe 3-5 letters forward, if possible, as a gut feeling.

Answer (score 0):

When you say n-grams, I'm going to assume you're talking about letters in a word, rather than words in a sentence (which probably is the most common usage). In this case, I would agree with Mark Rushakoff in that you could prune the candidates list to words including 3-5 characters more or less than the word you're controlling.

Another option would be to implement the [Levenshtein algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance) to find the edit distance between two words. This can be done quite efficiently: Firstly, through only checking against your pruned list. Secondly, through ending the distance calculation of a word prematurely once the edit distance exceeds some sort of limit (e.g. 3-5).

As a side note, I disagree with Mark on that you should ignore short words, as they are less frequently misspelt. A large portion of the misspelt words will be short words (such as "and" - "nad", "the" - "teh", "you" - "yuo"), simply because they are much more frequent.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient text for training, 3 is a good start. On the other hand, such a model will be quite big and bloat your spell checker.

You could also compare different settings based on [perplexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity).